# Object Oriented Issue in c#

Tags: c#, object

I need to know an efficient way to handle one object at the time to control one of this 3 classes without the switch. (Knowing the object type at any point)

Note : The method AddVertex is not overloaded, so its common to the parent class.

```
            switch (User.Action)
            {
                case Actions.NewVertex:
                    switch (GraphsType)
                    {
                        case GraphsType.None:
                            Graph.AddVertex(p); /*This is the parent class*/
                            break;
                        case GraphsType.UndirectedGraph: 
                            UndirectedGraph.AddVertex(p); /*This is a  derived class*/
                            break;
                        case GraphsType.DirectedGraph: 
                            DirectedGraph.AddVertex(p); /*This is a  derived class,*/
                            break;
                    }
             }
```

Comment: what is it your trying to handle? the graph types? is AddVertex a static method?

Comment: Yes, the graph types , and no , its not a static method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I see, you just want to write user command handler.

There are no big problem. Just make a dictionary (var GraphsType -> Graph).

```
 var dictionary = new Dictionary<GraphsType, Graph>() {
     { GraphsType.None, GraphObject },
     { GraphsType.UndirectedGraph, UndirectedGraphObject },
     { GraphsType.DirectedGraph, DirectedGraphObject },
 };
```

And use it:

```
dictionary[GraphType].AddVertex(v);
```

If your Graph, UndirectedGraph, DirectedGraph are static classes, you must save in dictionary it's type (`typeof(Graph)`) and then on type use reflection to find method and invoke it (`dictionary[GraphType].GetMethod(..).Invoke(...)`)

Comment: Np. Well, In reality you even can make Dictionary between Actions and MethodNames and then call it with reflection.